# some methods in Java that equally in Selenium Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I'm just googling the below codes of how to compare two images written to work with Selenium **Java**. However, I need to compare image files like the way below but in **Ruby** Selenium. Please guide me some methods that **equally** to getData(), getNumBands(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getSample() in **Ruby Selenium** ? Thanks much.

```
 try {
   original = ImageIO.read(new File(
     "originalFile"));
   copy = ImageIO.read(new File("copyFile"));

   ras1 = original.getData();
   ras2 = copy.getData();
//Comparing the the two images for number of bands,width & height.
   if (ras1.getNumBands() != ras2.getNumBands()
     || ras1.getWidth() != ras2.getWidth()
     || ras1.getHeight() != ras2.getHeight()) {
      ret=false;
   }else{
   // Once the band ,width & height matches, comparing the images.

   search: for (int i = 0; i < ras1.getNumBands(); ++i) {
    for (int x = 0; x < ras1.getWidth(); ++x) {
     for (int y = 0; y < ras1.getHeight(); ++y) {
      if (ras1.getSample(x, y, i) != ras2.getSample(x, y, i)) {
     // If one of the result is false setting the result as false and breaking the  loop.
       ret = false;
       break search;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [rjb](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/) a try. Install the gem with `JAVA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set as described in its homepage, and then you can call Java methods like:

```rb
require 'rjb'

Rjb::load(classpath = '.', jvmargs=[])

JImageIO = Rjb::import('javax.imageio.ImageIO')
JFile = Rjb::import('java.io.File')

original = JImageIO.read(JFile.new('a.jpg'))
ras1 = original.getData
puts ras1.getNumBands    #=> 3
puts ras1.getWidth       #=> 440
puts ras1.getHeight      #=> 322
puts ras1.getSample(0, 0, 0)  #=> 255
```

You can wrote the script as a daemon and query image comparison results via process communication to avoid frequent load/unload of the JVM.

Or you can use some Ruby library such as [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick). Refer to the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/), especially to the docs for [RMagick::ImageList](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html), [RMagick::Image](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html) and [RMagick::Pixel](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/struct.html#Pixel).

The code might be something like the following(I didn't do tests):

```rb
require 'RMagick'

original = RMagick::ImageList.new('a.jpg')   # ImageList
ras1 = original[0]   # Image
ras1.rows            # Height in pixels
ras1.columns         # Width in pixels
ras1.colorspace
ras1.matte           # colorspace and matte => getNumBands
ras1[0][1].red       # ras1.getSample(0, 1, 0)
ras1[0][1].green     # ras1.getSample(0, 1, 1)
ras1[0][1].blue      # ras1.getSample(0, 1, 2)
ras1[0][1].opacity   # ras1.getSample(0, 1, 3) useless when matte is false
```

Comment: Your answer is so sufficient and help me get more helpful knowledge. Thank you very much.